# .CommandText in C# for Postgres removes double quotes

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a small C# application that connects to a Postgres DB. All the table names start with capital letters so I found out that for the query to parse the tables need to have double-quotes. eg SELECT * FROM "Tablename".
I have this:

```
using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = npgsqlConnection;
string newstring = " \"x\" ";
string tab = newstring.Replace("x", tableName);
string strSQL = string.Format("select * from {0};", tab);
cmd.CommandText = strSQL; 
Console.WriteLine(strSQL);// I can see the double quotes here
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get an exception from cmd.ExecuteNonQuery as it can not find the table names. I found out that the double quotes were not included in the CommandText so it can not find TableX because it performs a SELECT * FROM TableX instead of SELECT * FROM "TableX".

Any suggestions will be helpful thanks.

Comment: And you're sure it's that and not, e.g. something like being in the wrong schema? ps; might clean your code up some to use an interpolated verbatim string `string strSQL = $@"select * from ""{tab}""";` pps; you can massively reduce your headache by renaming all your tables so you don't have to care about case sensitivity of their names; most coders I know take any possible steps to avoid case sens identifiers in databases; ppps; do not allow the user to supply data for `tab` variable -> SQL Injection risk; pull the table names from the db and look up what the user supplies in the pulled list

Comment: And what happens when you boil it down to `cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM \"TableNameHere\"";`? Same issue? Does Postgresql have a profiler so you can see what command is sent? I doubt that there is built in logic that strips quotes or does anything else with the command text value.

Comment: `so I found out that for the query to parse the tables need to have double-quotes` from my experience you don't need to enclose table names in quotes. Also what is the full exception, you never mention it. Also drop the format stuff and hardcode a select in the commandtext, for example: `SELECT * FROM TableName` or `SELECT version()`, does it succeed?

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks, I will check schemas. I have tried your suggestion and  I still get a "Relation does not exist" error

Comment: Thanks @zaggler, from what I found If the table names start with caps in Postgres you can only access them with double-quotes. Even running in heidisql a query without the double quotes will return a "relation not found error"

Comment: Please give us a [mre]: what is the actual table, schema and database names, and what is your connection string? I'm confused: is your question why it doesn't work without quotes, or is it when you have quotes it still doesn't work?

Comment: Run this in heidi: `ALTER TABLE "yoUrCrAzYTaBLeNamE"
RENAME TO yoUrCrAzYTaBLeNamE;` - now you can select it however you like

Answer (score 1):

Found out that I had to specify the schema name and it was not using the schema name in the connection string. The schema name should not be included in the double quotes.

This works:

```
string newstring = " \"x\" ";
string tab = newstring.Replace("x", tableName);
string strSQL = string.Format("select * from schema.{0};", tab);
cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
```

This will not work

```
string newstring = " \"x\" ";
string tab = newstring.Replace("x", schema.tableName);
string strSQL = string.Format("select * from schema.{0};", tab);
cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
```

On insert the columns should also be in double quotes.